# Difference between VOLUME in dockerfile and -v as docker run parameter

Tags: docker

Could some one help me to understand the difference between:

`VOLUME` command in dockerfile (image building layer)

and

-v paramter when issuing `docker run`**-v** /xyz/bla` command (container building layer).

-v parameter is for me clear, it simply exposes a directory from the host to the container and vice versa, but how does VOLUME in dockerfile behave differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Sir `Carlos Rafael Ramirez`

The difference between the is just that in case of `docer run -v` we can specify the destination on the host, but we cannot do that with VOLUME in Dockerfile.